# Retrieve refresh token via https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Tags: rest-api, login

Is there a way to retrieve refresh_token via https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token REST API call?

I've seen it's possible via connected app but we want to retrieve the refresh token via standard user/password login:

```
{
 "grant_type":"password",
 "username":"username",
 "password":"userpassword",
 "client_id":[CLIENT_ID],
 "client_secret":[CLIENT_SECRET],
 "format":"json"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: why would you want to do that, considering it is not a "best practice" can you expand on your use case?

Comment: I am going to advocate for not using the username and password grant flow because it's a no-no from a security perspective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between these authentication endpoints?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42445/whats-the-difference-between-these-authentication-endpoints)

Answer (score 3):

Refresh tokens are part of the OAuth 2.0 spec, and to use OAuth with Salesforce (at least the OAuth services that Salesforce provides out of the box), you need a connected app. This is true even for the username-password flow, which you shouldn't be using in general, which is demonstrated by the inclusion of the client id and secret in your example.

The JWT Bearer and Username-Password flows do not generate refresh tokens, so what you're asking for is not possible.